# How to shift a simple table left in Beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

[image]

I have an extremely simple table

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{12cm}}
            \toprule   
            \textbf{Artist} &  Description  \\   
            
            Eminem
            & Marshall Bruce Mathers III, known professionally as Eminem, is an American rapper, songwriter, and record producer. Eminem is among the best-selling music artists of all time, with estimated worldwide sales of more than 220 million records. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

I would like to make use of the spaces to the left of the screen.

I have tried using hspace{-1cm}. But nothing changed!

Can someone help?

Comment: Why you not make second column narrower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your table on the following way:

- I wouldnt shift table to the left (result will be unpleasent)
- for table use the `tabularx`
- reduce `tabcolsep`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.5cm}X}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Artist} &  Description  \\

            Eminem
            & Marshall Bruce Mathers III, known professionally as Eminem, is an American rapper, songwriter, and record producer. Eminem is among the best-selling music artists of all time, with estimated worldwide sales of more than 220 million records. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Are you aware that the width of your table is bigger than default width of beamer's frame? If you persist to move content of frame to the left for 10mm, you can employ `changepage` package and his macro `adjustwidth`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-10mm}{}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{12cm}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Artist} &  \textbf{Description}  \\
            Eminem
            & Marshall Bruce Mathers III, known professionally as Eminem, is an American rapper, songwriter, and record producer. Eminem is among the best-selling music artists of all time, with estimated worldwide sales of more than 220 million records. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and you will obtain this result:

[image]

Is this what you like to have. I would rather consider in such occasion reduce font used size accordingly or take some other measure.

As you noted in in comment, this table is not really your problem. So your question is not enterally clear then.

Comment: Hi Zarko. The problem is my text also has equations and I cannot wrap that around, only shift.

Comment: @Olórin, how should we know this? You no mentioned this in question nor provide more realistic MWE. You may consider to reduce font size. Are you aware that width of table in your MWE is bigger than width of frame? So shift of table to the left will not help much. See addendum to answer.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was my fault for not specifying my question clearly enough.